# Passing a factory into another in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, faker

I am trying to generate a test on Laravel.
What I was trying is to create a fictitious position name, then add 10 people for this position.

PositionsFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\Position::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
            'p_id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber($nbDigits = 8),
            'name' => $faker->word,
            'org' => $faker->word,
            'user_id' => 1
    ];
});
```

Here is my EmployeeFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\Employee::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'FirstName' => $faker->name,
        'LastName' => $faker->lastName,
        'pid' => $position->p_id,
        'org'=> $position->org,
        'user_id' => 1,
    ];    
});
```

Well here is one my my trials but it did not work

```
  for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
            $position = factory('App\Position')->create();

                factory('App\Employee',10)->create(
                    'pid' => $position->pid,
                    'org' => $position->org
                );
        }
```

I am trying to loop for 5 times and for each loop I want to create 10 employees with the same position Id. But obviously I am missing something.

I tried adding $position in the Employee factory, which works great.

```
$factory->define(App\Employee::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  $position = factory('App\Position')->create();
    return [
        'FirstName' => $faker->name,
        'LastName' => $faker->lastName,
        'pid' => $position->p_id,
        'org'=> $position->org,
        'user_id' => 1,
    ];

});
```

Is there a way to make something like,

```
$factory('App\Position',5)->create($factory('App\Employee',10));
```

Maybe I am missing something with call back but kinda lost. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `each` method which can be called after `create`:

```
// Generate 5 positions and execute a callback
// function for each position created
factory(App\Position::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($position) {
    // In the callback, generate 10 employees
    // and manually override the foreign key
    factory(App\Employee::class, 10)->create([
        'pid' => $position->id
    ]);
});
```

Further information on `each` and handling relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#relationships.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create them separatly and loop through collections.

```
$positions = factory('App\Position', 3)->make();
foreach ($positions as $position){
    $employes = factory('App\Employee', 3)->make();
    foreach ($employes as $employee){
        $employee->p_id = $position->id;
        //etc.. watever you want to connect
    }
}
```

now you have 1 collection of positions and 1 collection of employes devided of the positions
note that the make method does not save to database you need to manually save them

you could also change your factory as is stated in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#using-factories

yours would look like:

```
$factory->define(App\Employee::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'FirstName' => $faker->name,
        'LastName' => $faker->lastName,
        'org'=> $position->org,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'pid' => function () {
             return factory('App\Position')->create()->id;
         }

    ];    
});
```

This will create a position for each user the factory creates.
You could also use existing eloquent models instead if you have existing positions.

Comment: Thank you @Mike, your first proposal looks more like what I am trying to do, however it does not save the data:) I tried to use $employee->save() and ->create() neither worked. I think I'll need to read a bit more on it.

Comment: Using `create()` on the position factory and adding `$employee->save()` where my comment is should do the trick